New construction window nailing flange does not sit proud of siding on older house
I framed a rough opening for a new window install, proceeded to flash the corners and sill plate. I think added caulking around the perimeter, except the bottom, screwed the flange into the rough opening and then flashed the remaining perimeter, working from the sides then up.
However, our house is rather old and the previous siding remains underneath the current siding + insulation. Beaver Board > Old Siding > Insulation > Vinyl Siding is how our home is currently layered. The outermost portion of the window nailing flange (channel?) seems to be in the same plane as the insulation, meaning the siding won't slide into the window's native channel.
Did I make a mistake? Is there a solution? Please let me know.



@jay613 No. Our house is currently layered by fiberboard > siding > insulation > vinyl siding. That's how retrofits are done for older homes with wooden siding. It is kept to act as insulation. I did not rebuild some of the surrounding wall but I did remove the vinyl (most superficial siding), the insulation, and the old (deepest) siding so that I could screw the nailing flange onto the sheathing (fiberboard).
Do you have any recommendations? Considering there are windows on the other side of the home, I know that there is a solution to my current problem.

You should remove the windows and install them at the right depth.
Putting them at the right depth for your new siding is a good enough reason.  But you say it's an old house, and from the photos it appears you bought attractive windows that attempt to somewhat match the older windows or the style of the house.  You should install them as close as possible to the same depth as all the other outside windows.  New windows will change the look of the house in all kinds of ways.   Don't make it worse by having windows set at different depths from the outside wall.
You could build out the frame, but the advice in isherwood's answer about installing over sheathing may be better.  There are lots of tutorials on youtube about how to install windows.   But your key question is how to fix this, and the answer is, re-do it.

Thank you for stating this, as it helped me articulate the right query to get a tutorial for this exact problem.
Matt Risinger has a video on this exact scenario titled, Window Install with Thick Exterior Insulation, which details the idea of building out the rough opening in the z-axis.
Thank you to @isherwood as well. Though your idea of securing atop the foam is viable, I do not have faith in my ability to be delicate enough to install the window without denting or ruining the structural integrity of the foam supporting the window, thus I will opt for wood to hold up this window.

I think you've made a faulty assumption about how new construction would be done. I work on homes with extra foam sheathing on the exterior of OSB-sheathed walls. Windows are installed over the foam sheathing, not behind it.
Then, I don't think it's necessary to extend the framing around the rough opening. As long as you don't whack the nails home too hard the flanges will rest on the foam sheathing just fine. Once you insulate around the window with  low-expansion spray foam (highly recommended), it'll be locked in nicely.
Be sure you have the windows on plane with the interior wall before insulating. Measure between the window and the finished face of the wall at all four corners and adjust as needed. Your trim carpenter will thank you when it comes time to install jamb extensions and casing.
